# How can I insure that only a single alert(); is called while the browser is left unattended?

Tags: javascript, cookies, alert

I have a script that checks for a cookie. This cookie expires every ten minutes and if the cookie is expired, the script fires an alert reminding the user to save their progress. the problem I have encountered is if I leave the window open and unattended for a long period of time, I will have multiple `alert();` windows to click through when I return. It appears to only be two, but this could still be annoying for the end-user.

I know (or at least I think I know) there isn't a way to check if an `alert();` dialog is currently active or not, but are there any other solutions to this? How can I make sure a user that gets up from their computer doesn't return to multiple `alert();` pop-ups to click through?

For the sake of keeping it simple, the first part of my script uses [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.cookie#A_little_framework.3A_a_complete_cookies_reader.2Fwriter_with_full_unicode_support) framework, followed by the below code:

```
 function saveChecker() {
      if(docCookies.hasItem('saveReminder')) {
           console.log('cookie exists');
      }
      else {
           docCookies.setItem('saveReminder', 'Save Me', 600);
           alert('Save order message');
      }
 }
 setInterval(saveChecker, 5000);
```

Comment: Set something that says you've already popped the alert?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `setTimeout` instead of `setInterval`:

```
 function saveChecker() {
      if(docCookies.hasItem('saveReminder')) {
           console.log('cookie exists');
      }
      else {
           docCookies.setItem('saveReminder', 'Save Me', 600);
           alert('Save order message');
      }

      setTimeout(saveChecker, 5000);
 }
 setTimeout(saveChecker, 5000);
```

Due to the blocking nature of `alert`, the new timeout will only be set once the alert is closed.